# Cronjob to Run and then Terminate

Tags: cron, scheduling

I want to add a cron entry that does something like:

```
00 00 * * * * /tmp/script.sh
```

Is there something I can add to the end of the line, so that when it is finished, it will remove the line out of my cron?

Also, if there is a better way to do it, I would definitely want that information instead.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Cron is used to schedule a job to run repeatedly. What you want is `at`, which schedules a job to run one-time. For your example you can write:

```
at midnight
```

This will bring up an interactive prompt where you can enter `/tmp/script.sh` followed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.

Comment: Perfect!  Just what I needed!